# Why does ALSA snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size react to the size of local stack frame allocations?

Tags: alsa

Distro: Debian 9.11

Compiler: gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516

ALSA version: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.9.0-11-amd64.

Please consider the following minimal reproducible example (now updated, with more error handling):

```
/**
 * Trying to set some parameters for ALSA.
 *
 * Code from: http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html
 *
 */

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PCM_DEVICE "default"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int err;
    snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;

    if((err = snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, PCM_DEVICE, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Can't open \"%s\" PCM device. %s\n", PCM_DEVICE, snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(pcm_handle, params);

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(pcm_handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Can't set interleaved mode. %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(pcm_handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Can't set format. %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    int channels = 2;
    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pcm_handle, params, channels)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Can't set channels number. %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    int rate = 44100;
    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(pcm_handle, params, &rate, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Can't set rate. %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    printf("PCM name: '%s'\n", snd_pcm_name(pcm_handle));
    printf("PCM state: %s\n", snd_pcm_state_name(snd_pcm_state(pcm_handle)));

    int ch;
    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params, &ch)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to get the number of channels: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    if(ch > 1) {
        printf("Channels: %i, stereo\n", ch);
    }
    else if(ch == 1) {
        printf("Channels: %i, mono\n", ch);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error: Unknown number of channels (%d).\n", ch);

        return 1;
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &ch, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to get the rate: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    printf("Rate: %d bps\n", ch);

    int dir;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t period_size = 1024;

    printf("Attempting to set the period size to %d\n", period_size);

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(pcm_handle, params, &period_size, &dir)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to set the period size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    printf("Attempting to get the period size.\n");

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &period_size, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to get the period size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    printf("Period size is now: %zd\n", period_size);

    int period_time = -1;

    printf("Attempting to get the period time.\n");

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &period_time, NULL)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to get the period time: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    printf("Period time: %d\n", period_time);

    int buffer_size = 4096;

    printf("Attempting to set the buffer size to: %d\n", buffer_size);

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size(pcm_handle, params, buffer_size)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to set the buffer size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    printf("Finalizing hw params.\n");

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params(pcm_handle, params)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Can't set harware parameters. %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    snd_pcm_uframes_t temp;

    printf("Attempting to get the buffer size.\n");

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(params, &temp)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to get the buffer size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    printf("Buffer size is now: %d\n", temp);

    if((err = snd_pcm_drain(pcm_handle)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to drain the pcm handle: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_close(pcm_handle)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Unable to close the pcm handle: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When char test[5] exists, I get this output:

```
PCM name: 'default'
PCM state: OPEN
Channels: 2, stereo
Rate: 44100 bps
Attempting to set the period size to 1024
Attempting to get the period size.
Period size is now: 1024
Attempting to get the period time.
Period time: -1
Attempting to set the buffer size to: 4096
Finalizing hw params.
Attempting to get the buffer size.
Buffer size is now: 523774
```

Note the "Buffer size is now: 523774". The expected output is given below:

However, if I change test[5] to test[4] or less (or remove the statement altogether), recompile, and run, I get:

```
PCM name: 'default'
PCM state: OPEN
Channels: 2, stereo
Rate: 44100 bps
Attempting to set frames to 1024
Frames is now: 1024
Attempting to set the buffer size to: 4096
Buffer size is now: 4096
```

I must be abusing the ALSA API, be doing something else weird I don't realize, or the ALSA API is broken.

Why does it react to this trivial stack allocation of 5 bytes?

Note that a higher value than 5 also produces this problem, such as a word aligned number of 32. I don't think has to do with stack alignment or something of that sort.

**Compiler notes, how to reproduce:**

Copy/paste the minimal example into broken_alsa.c

Then issue:

```
$ gcc broken_alsa.c -lasound
$ ./a.out
```

Remove the char temp[5] (or set it to 4), and it should work.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue, but it smells like an alignment issue. Hard to confirm because you don't tell which compiler and for what target architecture you are compiling. It would be nice if you provide all your compile and link options (full compile/link command lines).

Comment: Please check the return value of all function calls; some might have failed.

Comment: @Pedro Please see my updated code example and updated output text in my question. I don't think it is an alignment issue. I've also included what compiler, distro and ALSA version, and I have added compilation notes.

Comment: @CL Thank you. I have added this, and did indeed find a problem when getting the period size, this call fails under the presence of the 5 byte array on the stack, and succeeds when it is removed -- however, for me, this unfortunately only raises new questions.

Comment: @CL I also had an incredible error in the code, forgive me, which I don't know how worked itself in there relating to lack of another set of parentheses when doing function calls ... I fixed that, but I'm back to the original problem with the value changing under the presence of this stack array.

Comment: I still can't reproduce your problem with the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near()`, initialize `dir` to zero.